# Retornar IObservable em um método

Tags: c#, interface

Eu tenho um método que precisa retornar um IObservable, porém estou tendo muita dificuldade. Há pouco conteúdo a respeito dessa interface e o que encontro exige o uso da extensão Reactive (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985(v=vs.103))
Alguém com conhecimento a respeito da interface IObservable pode me confirmar se realmente só é possível retornar um IObservable em um método com o uso dessa extensão?

```
public class Graph<T> : IGraph<T>
{
    public Graph(IEnumerable<ILink<T>> links)
    {

    }

    public IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> RoutesBetween(T source, T target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Tamara, essa mania nova da Microsoft de traduzir tudo está problemática... Você viu esse exemplo?
[Como implementar um observador](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-implement-an-observer) [IObservable<T> Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Você instalou o pacote [System.Reactive.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/4.2.0-preview.63) ?

Comment: @FabioIn Oi Fabio. Eu cheguei a ver sim, mas não me ajudou muito, infelizmente.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Oi Virgilio. Não instalei. Só pra explicar, eu estou fazendo um teste para uma empresa e a adição de referência está bloqueada no projeto e portanto não consigo instalar o pacote. Por isso gostaria de saber se é possível retornar IObservable sem ter que utilizar Reactive.

Comment: Tamara tem sim, porque `IObservable` é uma `interface` é só implementar uma classe e no retorno utiliza a instância dessa classe

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Virgilio Obrigada! Não tinha pensado nisso. Vou tentar e aviso aqui se der certo